# Does Laravel Mix transpile to ES5?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am using javascript to enhance a page in a Laravel application.  I want to use an ES6 feature, namely template strings, but it is not supported in IE.  If I use Laravel mix to compile my assets, will it transpile to ES5 out of the box?

I have had a look through the Mix documentation and the configuration files but can't find any info on this.  Any hints on info sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated this further and it seems that Webpack does not transpile out of the box, and nor does Laravel Mix.  I would need to use a Babel loader or similar to make this happen.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong and misleading, and it shouldn't be the accepted answer: it's true that Webpack does not transpile out of the box, but Laravel Mix does, so there's no need to add a Babel Loader.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fresh installation of Laravel (v. 5.7) with [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) (v. 2.1.14) and it does transpile to es5 out of the box. I thought that this was a recent addition, but looking at the GitHub project I see that Babel has been in Laravel Mix since the [initial commit](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/commit/2eb994cbfbb3c9efdbc2be16a6663b2b02bfd254#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2).

Comment: Ok. good to know.  I'll check it out next time I start a new project.

Comment: Once you have checked, shouldn't this be the accepted answer (as it states the contrary of the current accepted answer)?